# Page Builder product carousel only one item per slide always

Tags: magento2, rwd, page-builder, slick

Is it possible to have one product per slide always no matter the size of the screen using the product Carousel with page builder?

The default is 5 items.

Answer (score 1):

In vendor/magento/module-page-builder/etc/view.xml the default amount of slides per breakpoint are set. You can probably override this by adding the part starting from  to YourVendor/YourTheme/etc/view.xml and setting 1 everywhere

Answer (score 1):

This question is very old but I came across it in my search for the answer to a similar question. In case it helps someone else, I was able to change how many slides were shown in my product carousels by adding the following code to my `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/etc/view.xml` file.

```
<vars module="Magento_PageBuilder">
    <var name="breakpoints">
        <var name="desktop">
            <var name="options">
                <var name="products">
                    <var name="default">
                        <var name="slidesToShow">3</var>
                    </var>
                </var>
            </var>
        </var>
        <var name="tablet">
            <var name="options">
                <var name="products">
                    <var name="default">
                        <var name="slidesToShow">2</var>
                    </var>
                </var>
            </var>
        </var> 
        <var name="mobile">
            <var name="options">
                <var name="products">
                    <var name="default">
                        <var name="slidesToShow">1</var>
                    </var>
                </var>
            </var>
        </var>
        <var name="mobile-small">
            <var name="options">
                <var name="products">
                    <var name="default">
                        <var name="slidesToShow">1</var>
                    </var>
                </var>
            </var>
        </var>
    </var>
</vars>
```